Why am I getting this key size error in my AES GCM file encryption/decryption program?
I get the output of the key and iv, including the key and iv size which is 32 for key and 12 for the iv. However, at the setKeyWithIV line the error message is thrown. I think this is due to the key being cofused with the iv as the error says that 12 is not a valid key length. Im not sure how to fix this nor can i find any information about it on the CryptoPP site. When I Run the following program, I get the following error message:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidKeyLength'
what():  AES: 12 is not a valid key length
Aborted (core dumped).

#include "cryptopp/cryptlib.h"
#include "cryptopp/files.h"
#include "cryptopp/hex.h"
#include "cryptopp/osrng.h"
#include "cryptopp/modes.h"
#include "cryptopp/aes.h"
#include "cryptopp/gcm.h"
#include "cryptopp/secblock.h"
#include "cryptopp/pwdbased.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

using namespace CryptoPP;


void printHex(const byte *data, size_t size, const std::string &label); //for debuggin to print hex values

void deriveKeyAndIV(const std::string &password, byte *key, size_t keySize, byte *iv, size_t ivSize);
//for deriving key and iv using hkdf

void encryptFile(const std::string &password, const std::string &inputFile, const std::string &outputFile);
// Function prototype for encryptFile

void decryptFile(const std::string &password, const std::string &inputFile, const std::string &outputFile);
// Funciton prototype for decryptFile

void printHex(const byte *data, size_t size, const std::string &label) {
    CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder(new CryptoPP::FileSink(std::cout));
    std::cout << label << ": ";
    encoder.Put(data, size);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    //all of print hex for debuggin purposes
}


void deriveKeyAndIV(const std::string &password, byte *key, size_t keySize, byte *iv, size_t ivSize) {

    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock derived(keySize + ivSize);
    //the keysize & ivSize is not defined.
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock salt(16);
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    prng.GenerateBlock(salt, 16);

    CryptoPP::PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC <CryptoPP::SHA256> kdf;
    kdf.DeriveKey(derived.data(), derived.size(), 0, (const byte *) password.data(), password.size(), salt.data(),
                  salt.size(), 1000000);

    std::memcpy(key, derived.data(), keySize);
    std::memcpy(iv, derived.data() + keySize, ivSize);


    std::cout << "Derived key size: " << keySize << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Derived iv size: " << ivSize << std::endl;
}

void encryptFile(const std::string &password, const std::string &inputFile, const std::string &outputFile) {
    //Encrypt file using AES-256-GCM mode

    const size_t keySize = 32;
    const size_t ivSize = 12;
    const size_t TAG_SIZE = 16;

    byte key[32], iv[12];
    deriveKeyAndIV(password, key, keySize, iv, ivSize);

    printHex(key, sizeof(key), "Encryption Key");
    printHex(iv, sizeof(iv), "IV");
    //debugging

    CryptoPP::GCM<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption encryption;
    encryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));


    CryptoPP::AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter aef(encryption, new CryptoPP::FileSink(
                                                        inputFile.c_str()), //Write the encrypted data and mac to the outputfile
                                                false, TAG_SIZE);

    FileSink ivSink(outputFile.c_str(), true);
    ivSink.Put(iv, sizeof(iv));
    ivSink.MessageEnd();

    aef.ChannelPut(CryptoPP::AAD_CHANNEL, iv, sizeof(iv));
    //Adding the IV to the AAD channel (MAC calculation)

    FileSource fs(inputFile.c_str(), false);
    byte buffer[4096];

    while (true) {
        size_t bytesRead = fs.Get(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (bytesRead == 0) break;
        aef.ChannelPut(DEFAULT_CHANNEL, buffer, bytesRead);
    }

    aef.ChannelMessageEnd(CryptoPP::DEFAULT_CHANNEL);


    aef.ChannelMessageEnd(CryptoPP::AAD_CHANNEL);
    //End the AAD channel

    aef.MessageEnd();

    std::cout << "IV after encryption: ";
    printHex(iv, sizeof(iv), "IV after encryption");
    std::cout << "MAC after encryption: ";
    //nothing yet -_-

}


void decryptFile(const std::string &password, const std::string &inputFile, const std::string &outputFile) {
    //Decrypt file using AES-256-GCM mode

    const size_t keySize = 32;
    const size_t ivSize = 12;

    byte key[32], iv[12];

    if (sizeof(key) != 32) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid key size. Must be 32 bytes for AES-256.");
    }

    const size_t TAG_SIZE = 16;

    FileSource fs(inputFile.c_str(), false);
    fs.Pump(12);
    fs.Get(iv, 12);
    //read the iv from the beggining of the file

    std::string cipherText;
    FileSource(inputFile.c_str(), true, new StringSink(cipherText));

    std::string enc = cipherText.substr(12, cipherText.length() - 12 - TAG_SIZE);
    std::string mac = cipherText.substr(cipherText.length() - TAG_SIZE);
    //Extracting the cipherText and the MAC from the cipherText

    CryptoPP::GCM<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption decryption;
    decryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

    CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter adf(decryption, new CryptoPP::FileSink(outputFile.c_str()),
                                                CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::MAC_AT_BEGIN |
                                                CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION,
                                                TAG_SIZE);               //Decrypting the cipher text

    adf.ChannelPut(CryptoPP::DEFAULT_CHANNEL, (const byte *) (mac.data()), mac.size());
    //Adding the MAC to the channel

    adf.ChannelPut(CryptoPP::AAD_CHANNEL, iv, sizeof(iv));
    //Adding the IV to the AAD channel (MAC calculation)

    adf.ChannelPut(CryptoPP::DEFAULT_CHANNEL, (const byte *) (enc.data()), enc.size());
    //Adding the cipher text to the channel

    adf.ChannelMessageEnd(CryptoPP::AAD_CHANNEL);
    adf.ChannelMessageEnd(CryptoPP::DEFAULT_CHANNEL);
    //End the AAD channel and the channel


    bool result = adf.GetLastResult();
    if (!result) {
        throw CryptoPP::Exception(CryptoPP::Exception::OTHER_ERROR, "MAC check failed");
    }

    try {

        std::string retrieved;
        size_t n = (size_t) -1;
        //remove data from channel

        adf.SetRetrievalChannel(CryptoPP::DEFAULT_CHANNEL);
        n = (size_t) adf.MaxRetrievable();
        retrieved.resize(n);
        //resize the retrieved string to the maximum size possible

        if (n > 0) {
            adf.Get((byte *) retrieved.data(), n);
        }
        //get the data from the channel

        FileSink output(outputFile.c_str());
        output.Put((const byte *) retrieved.data(), retrieved.size());
        //write the retrieved data to the output file

    } catch (const CryptoPP::InvalidCiphertext &e) {
        std::cerr << "Decryption error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Starting program...." << std::endl;

    std::string password;
    std::cout << "Enter password: ";
    std::cin >> password;

    std::string inputFile;
    std::string outputFile;


    //try{

    char choice;
    std::cout << "Do you want to encrypt or decrypt? (e/d): ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 'e') {
        std::cout << "Enter the input file name for encryption: ";
        std::cin >> inputFile;

        outputFile = inputFile + ".enc";

        encryptFile(password, inputFile, outputFile);


        std::cout << inputFile << " was encrypted sucessfully." << std::endl;
    } else if (choice == 'd') {
        std::cout << "Enter the input file name for decryption: ";
        std::cin >> inputFile;
        outputFile = inputFile + ".dec";

        decryptFile(password, inputFile, outputFile);
        std::cout << inputFile << " was decrypted sucessfully." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Invalid choice. Please enter 'e' for encryption or 'd' for decryption." << std::endl;
    }

    /*} catch (const std::exception &e) {
                   std::cerr << "An Error occured: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } */

    std::cout << "Program ended" << std::endl;
    return 0;

}

Ive tried adding debugging, locating where the issue is occurring and changing the key and IV sizes, im not sure what to do now.

What line is the exception thrown from? What about all the debugging output you've got code for, doesn't nothing get output?

No, The key and IV size is outputed along with the key and iv however i get the error message. I think the error is around the SetKeyWithIV line.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
